# Icon flags with value in dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap dropdown menu with options to select. I want to add country flag near text on left side. And I did it, but the problem is when i select the option in dropdown and submit it, the flag is sent via php/html too. I dont know how to place it here to do not submit the flag with `<li>` and to have flag on the left side.

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-select">
  <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  <input class="btn-select-input" id="select_league" name="league" type="hidden">
  <span class="btn-select-value">All leagues</span>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
    <li class=""><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</li>
  </ul>            
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Drop-downs with FontAwesome & Font Flag Icons

**FontAwesome Demo**

```js
   $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
         .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

```css
.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5>Select Dropdown with FontAwesome Icons</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">All Leagues</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-fw"></i>Brazil</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-fw"></i>Brazil</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-fw"></i>Brazil</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Font Flag Icons Demo**

```js
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
         .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h5>Font Flag Icons</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">All Leagues</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-br"></span>Brazil</a></li>                 
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Its working on your html dropdown, but i cannot implant on this which Im using: [link] (http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2pP70)

Comment: I have seen your given link. Here is demo with bunch of Bootstrap Select boxes. Do you want to add this icons into that select boxes ?

Comment: Yes. In to this which i sent to you. Custom icon like from my code, not icons from bootstrap

Comment: I have created new fiddle with your given select boxes and I have integrated icons also. Please check the demo. https://jsfiddle.net/nutc2f13/1/

Comment: @user3307783, If you are going to use my example as reference, might as well accept it as the answer.

Comment: The example looks good, but when i submit this (made this before) its submit the flag with value too. So its not just be Brazil, it will send span too

Comment: I didn't get you...!

Comment: Check, i edited post. You will see my submit value from dropdown and response on another table. So when i submit value from dropdown, it send icon too, i just need value of Brazil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115543/discussion-between-sayed-rafeeq-and-user3307783).

Comment: what is .btn.form-control for? It's not used in ay of the code, so none of the css adds anything, and your JS is spitting out an error TypeError: $target.closest(...).find(...).text(...).end().children(...).dropdown is not a function