# Show Images with name in option tag in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using vue with html and i am trying to populate options in select tag with countries their names and their flags
Names and other things are being displayed ok and even the url of image is being shown in code when i inspect it and it is valid but it not showing inside the options tags
Is it some styling issue
P.s For now i dont want to use v-select

My Select

```
<select name="country" class="selectedImg">
<option>Select your country</option>
    <option class="text-center"   v-for="row in pics" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + row.flag+ ')' }" style="background-size: 10px;

    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;" :value="row.flag">
                        {{row.name}}<img :src="row.flag" width="10"/>   
        </option>
</select>
```

[image: My Select Box]

and the url being shown and it is valid

[image: Image Url set in background]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add images inside a option tag. I think you have three options here:

- Use CSS and add the image like a `background-image` (in the same option tag or in the `:after` or `:before` pseudo elements)
- Use a icon to render the flag instead of the image (using a library such as FontAwesome or https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css
- Use Select2 (or tail.select or similar) library in order to be able to have smarter selects that can handle html inside the option.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answering it 
I used flag icon library but it also doesnt shows flags inside option tag

Comment: This link shows you with examples how to do it with Font Awesome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005348/icon-flags-with-value-in-dropdown-menu?rq=1

Comment: i know 
i wanted to do it with <select></select>